# Fontfamily with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I'm trying to install a custom fontfamily, named Agenda, in my Latex document.
I use XeLatex, so i tried to load the font with \fontspec:

Using this code, the font works great:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=10mm,bmargin=10mm,lmargin=10mm,rmargin=5mm} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Agenda}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Agenda Medium}
 hello \textbf{world}
\end{document}
```

Adding a word with an "umlaut" to the text, like "Änderung" or " "Anderung", I get the error :
     Type2 Charstring Parser: Parsing charstring failed: (stataus=-1, stack=5).

When I change the font to a windows system font font like Arial:

```
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Arial}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Arial Regular}
```

...I get this error:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! The font "Arial Regular" cannot be found.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also add a link to a resource for the font, please. And a suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Oh, I should have searched earlier, the font is not free … makes it hard to help.

Comment: You will not be able to use this font. Perhaps you can find a newer version or if the license permits it you could try to use e.g. fontforge to repair it. Search the xetex mailing list for more informations: http://tug.org/mailman/mmsearch/xetex?config=xetex&restrict=&exclude=&method=and&format=short&sort=score&words=seac.

Answer (score 7):

`\newfontfamily` is only used for additional fonts, not for the main one.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\TGPagella[Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily\Agenda[Mapping=tex-text]{Agenda-Medium}

\begin{document}
hello \textbf{world}

\TGPagella
hello \textbf{world}

\Agenda
hello \textbf{world}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this works, Thank you! So I can use Arial, if Agenda doesn't works. When I use Agenda with your solution, I get the same error like before. Maybe you have an idea how I can get Agenda to work with the german language?

Comment: see my edited anwer. I suppose there is no `Agenda` but only `Agenda-Medium` and `AgendaLight`

Comment: No, it still doesnt works, sorry.

Comment: Do you have the OpenType or TrueType version version of Agenda?

Comment: I have the OpenType of Agenda.

Comment: That is what I used in my example!

Comment: When I change it to Agenda, I get always the "seac" error mentioned above.

Comment: _Not_ with my example if you use it with umaluts ! In your code you are mixing `pdflatex` and `xelatex` font packages and font setting. That cannot work.