# Create a custom numbered list with little balls and gray rectangle (also with the shadows)

Tags: tikz-pgf, numbering, lists

**ADDENDUM: I add, although it is possible to have the shadows on the dots (not active) as you can see from the following picture.**

[image]

I ask you for your help to create a **custom numbered list** with a font other than the default, with a gray rectangle and small blue balls that indicate the degree of difficulty of an exercise.

I hope you can create an identical source.

[image]

Comment: Last edition introduces a "new question", so It would be better that you click on "Ask a question" and start a new question that you can link with this one. After that you can edit again this one to delete the new question.

Comment: In any case, what does "to get the shadows on the dots" means? Do you want a fixed amount of gray dots under the number with only some of them colored in red?

Comment: @Ignasi, Dearest, thanks for your answer. I would like to have a small change of the source. Exactly. I want a fixed amount of gray dots under the number with only some of them colored in red. 3 balls with 2 gray, a red dot (for example) indicates difficulties 1.

Comment: I have provided an **ADDENDUM** to my answer to address your recent extension request.

Comment: I've also updated the answer in order to solve your last request.

Comment: The new addition isn't a question. It also seems to contradict the main question. Confused.

Comment: @cfr I wanted an integration of my question.

Comment: "Behold, I make all things new" https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615482/a-binary-code-index-for-enumerate-items-using-stackengine/615489#615489

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See **ADDENDUM** for OP's follow-on.

EDITED to make a separate environment, `benumerate`.

Here, inside the `benumerate` environment, the optional argument to `\item` indicates the difficulty level.

Here is a brief description of what the new/revised macros do, since they may require some alteration if fonts are changed, as desired by the OP.

`\difbox`: creates the "difficulty-box" under the item number.  The size and color of the gray box are provided by a `\rule` and `\color` macro.  It calls on `\makeballs` to set the proper number of circles in the gray box.

`\makeballs`: the recursive macro that places a set of sequential `\bullet`s as the circles in the box.

`benumerate`: the environment that accomplishes all this, by redefining a few things and calling on `enumerate`.

`\item`: inside `benumerate`, `\item` is redefined to take the difficulty level as the optional argument (default `1`), which it saves before calling on the usual `\item`.

`\labelenumi`: the label redefinition inside `benumerate`, which stacks the `\difbox` `1pt` below the enumeration label (which has been set in bold, sans font of an altered color).

EDITED to `\smash` the `\labelenumi`, since the low-hanging box was affecting line spacing of the item content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,lipsum}
\let\svitem\item
\newcommand\difbox[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{\color{gray!30}\rule{5ex}{1.15ex}}{%
    \color{cyan!60!black}$\mkern1mu\makeballs{#1}$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\def\makeballs#1{\ifnum#1>0\relax{\bullet}%
  \expandafter\makeballs\the\numexpr#1-1\relax\fi}
\newenvironment{benumerate}
{\renewcommand\item[1][1]{\def\difficulty{##1}\svitem}%
  \def\labelenumi{\smash{\stackunder[1pt]{\color{cyan!60!black}%
  \bfseries\sffamily\theenumi}{\difbox{\difficulty}}}}%
  \enumerate}{\endenumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{benumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{32}
\item[2] \lipsum[4]
\item[3] \lipsum[4]
\item[4] \lipsum[3]
\end{benumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

To handle the OP's follow on extension request, the solution is trivial.  After the invocation of `\makeballs{#1}` in the `difbox` macro, add `\textcolor{red}{\makeballs{\the\numexpr4-#1\relax}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,lipsum}
\let\svitem\item
\newcommand\difbox[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{\color{gray!30}\rule{5ex}{1.15ex}}{%
    \color{cyan!60!black}$\mkern1mu\makeballs{#1}%
    \textcolor{red}{\makeballs{\the\numexpr4-#1\relax}}$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\def\makeballs#1{\ifnum#1>0\relax{\bullet}%
  \expandafter\makeballs\the\numexpr#1-1\relax\fi}
\newenvironment{benumerate}
{\renewcommand\item[1][1]{\def\difficulty{##1}\svitem}%
  \def\labelenumi{\smash{\stackunder[1pt]{\color{cyan!60!black}%
  \bfseries\sffamily\theenumi}{\difbox{\difficulty}}}}%
  \enumerate}{\endenumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{benumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{32}
\item[2] \lipsum[4]
\item[3] \lipsum[4]
\item[4] \lipsum[3]
\end{benumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but wouldn't it be safer to create a new list environment rather than redefine `\item` globally?

Comment: Very good! Thank you so much for your help Steven and Alan. But can I have some more details for the source? Why there is a few space between the first and the second straight line? I use Optima font with symbols computer modern. If I use \sffamily, the font of the numbers is Optima font. It is possible to have another bold font that is not default and that I can find into MikTeX packages? Agenda bold not exists in LaTeX. Best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano I am sorry, but I do not have access to the Optima font, so I can't tailor the particular solution.  However, I will edit my answer with more explanation, so that you can alter certain settings to suit your need, as required.  I am sorry I don't understand your comment "Why there is a few space between the first and the second straight line".

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for kind and detailed answer. For example, you can look the nr. 33. Between the first row and the second row there is a little space (\vspace) adjacent to the number 33, to the rectangle with the little balls. For the others rows there are not problems. Is there a solution? For the source I have understand all. Steven, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @Sebastiano Now I see what you are saying.  I will fix it.  Done.

Comment: Thanksss Steven. For the font of the numbers I will use typewriter font (into MikTeX packages) or Optima font. Perfect!!!! I look now.

Comment: @Sebastiano You are welcome.  To change to tt font family, replace `\sffamily` with `\ttfamily` in the `\labelenumi` definition.

Comment: With all my heart, thanks Steven. I have look on another pc using the link https://papeeria.com/landing. Infact, yesterday I have replace \sffamily with \ttfamily. Grazieeeeeeeeeeee.

Comment: Dear Steven I still should to undestand the structure of the site. It is not difficult, but yet I should create many exercises and test for my students of Maths, Physics and ICT. Best regardsssss.

Comment: Steven, excuse me another with my heart. You can see at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343117/new-request-for-create-a-custom-numbered-list-with-little-balls-gray-rectangle. Yet I have not undestand as work this site (i.e. as change an request already written, contact users, ecc.). Excuse me again.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you so much for your patience and interest in my application. Excuse me a lot of delay due to a number of school obligations.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi. Yesterday I have add your new code into my `.tex` document. I have a warning: `Missing \begin{document}`. I think that the question is your new added: `\color{cyan!60!black}$\mkern1mu\makeballs{#1}%
    \textcolor{red}{\makeballs{\the\numexpr4-#1\relax}}$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}`. I obtain two page for my long source. The first page is blank. The second is perfect.

Comment: @Sebastiano I verified again that my code compiles properly.  Generally the error you describe arises when you try to output text in the preamble.  This can occur inadvertantly, for example, with a missing backslash, a misplaced percent sign, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Another implementation with `tcolorbox`. Instead of an `\item` inside an `enumerate` environment, a new environment `problem` will be used. This environment uses a mandatory parameter (difficulty 1 to 4) and an optional one to change particular formatting options in one or more problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{problem}[2][]{%
   breakable,
    blankest,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    left=\tcboxedtitlewidth+1mm,
    top=0pt,
    colback=white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
    coltitle={cyan!60!black},
    colbacktitle=white,
    colframe=white,
    title=\thetcbcounter, 
    overlay unbroken and first={%
        \node[fill=gray!30, inner sep=1pt, minimum width=\tcboxedtitlewidth, 
                outer sep=0pt, text=cyan!60!black, anchor=north] at (title.south) 
                {\foreach \i in {1,...,#2}{\if#2gt1{\,}\fi$\bullet$}};}, 
    #1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{problem}{1}
\lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}{4}
\lipsum[3]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}{2}
\lipsum[4]
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

In this case, four balls are placed below the title and their color is decided with a conditional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{problem}[2][]{%
   breakable,
    blankest,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    left=\tcboxedtitlewidth+2mm,
    top=0pt,
    colback=white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
    coltitle={cyan!60!black},
    colbacktitle=white,
    colframe=white,
    title=\thetcbcounter, 
    overlay unbroken and first={%
        \node[fill=gray!30, inner sep=1pt, 
            minimum width=\tcboxedtitlewidth, 
            outer sep=0pt, 
            anchor=north] at (title.south) {%
            \foreach \i in {1,...,4}{%
            \ifnum\i>#2%
                \,\textcolor{cyan!60!black}{$\bullet$}%
            \else
                \,\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$}%           
            \fi}};}, 
    #1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{problem}{1}
\lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}{3}
\lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}{4}
\lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kind Ignasi thanks for another help for my question. I like you work too. I use LaTeX from 2002 but I not know all packages and I not understand the way to build the little balls to indicate the difficulty for exercises or problems. Now I use a long source with fonts optima with modern computer symbols, and I have not difficulty to paste to the my source. Thanks lot lot for your precius help. Yesterday, I have effectuate the registration into the excellent web site. Best regards.

Comment: I apologize for the delay of my most sincere thanks for your answer due to the many commitments at school.

Comment: I've tried to compile the code....What does this error mean? "! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/blankest' and I am going t
o ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."

Comment: @ryuk It means that you are using an outdated `tcolorbox` version which doesn't have `blankest` defined. Update `tcolorbox` and the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a third solution using a standard [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) environment together with [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz).

The idea is to create a new `enumerate` environment, which I have called `questions`, and then use `before=\fakeitem` to replace the standard `\item` command in this environment with a new command that typesets the "difficulty dots". The "difficulty dots" are then drawn using a `pics` construct inside a `\tikz` call.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzset{pics/question/.style args={#1,#2}{
             code={
                \node[teal] at (0.5,0.35) {\textsf{#1}};
                \fill[gray!30] (0.1,0) rectangle (0.9,0.2);
                \foreach \ball [evaluate=\ball as \x using {0.5+(\ball-0.5-#2/2)*0.2)}] in {1,...,#2} {
                    \fill[teal] (\x,0.1) circle (2.5pt);
                }
            }
        }
}

\let\realitem\item% save a copy of the \item command
\newcommand\fakeitem[1][\relax]{%
   \refstepcounter{questionsi}% increment the counter
   \realitem[\smash{\tikz[baseline]{\draw(0,-0.2) pic{question={\thequestionsi,#1}};}}]%
}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}% define a new enumerate environment
\setlist[questions]{  % set properties of the questions environment
   label=\arabic*.,   % label format
   leftmargin=*,      % indent labels
   before=\let\item\fakeitem, % change the \item command
   resume,            % continuous numbering
}

\begin{document}

      \begin{questions}[start=32]
        \item[2] \lipsum[4]
        \item[3] \lipsum[4]
        \item[4] \lipsum[3]
      \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

**Addendum**

I small tweak of the `\fakeitem` macro answers the followup question in the post:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzset{
  pics/question/max/.initial = 5, % maximum number of balls
  pics/question/.style args={#1,#2}{
             code={
                \node[teal] at (0.5,0.35) {\textsf{#1}};
                \fill[gray!30] (0.1,0) rectangle (0.9,0.2);
                \def\qmax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pics/question/max}}
                 \foreach \ball [evaluate=\ball as \x using {0.1+(\ball-0.5)*0.8/\qmax}] in {1,...,\qmax} {
                    \fill[\ifnum\ball>#2 teal\else red\fi] (\x,0.1) circle (2.5pt);
                }
            }
        }
}

\let\realitem\item% save a copy of the \item command
\newcommand\fakeitem[1][\relax]{%
   \refstepcounter{questionsi}% increment the counter
   \realitem[\smash{\tikz[baseline]{\draw(0,-0.2) pic{question={\thequestionsi,#1}};}}]%
}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}% define a new enumerate environment
\setlist[questions]{  % set properties of the questions environment
   label=\arabic*.,   % label format
   leftmargin=*,      % indent labels
   before=\let\item\fakeitem, % change the \item command
   resume,            % continuous numbering
}

\begin{document}

      \begin{questions}[start=32]
        \item[2] \lipsum[4]
        \item[3] \lipsum[4]
        \item[4] \lipsum[3]
      \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

By default, 5 dots are printed for each question. This can be changed using, for example, `\tikzset{pics/question/max=4}` to set it to 4 dots. In theory this could be arbitrary but in practice it should be in the range 2-5. Here is a sample of the new output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Andrew. Also your solution is very good. Can you see this link, please? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343117/new-request-for-create-a-custom-numbered-list-with-little-balls-gray-rectangle. 
So kindly would you be able to modify my source of this link, giving me the opportunity to change the size of the numbers with a font that is very similar to that of the image (Agenda.ttf), put a paragraph with the same font, with the number 5 in gray and the rest in the red?

Comment: Now I have visited this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167532/fontfamily-with-xelatex. As is it possible change my source with the considerations at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343117/new-request-for-create-a-custom-numbered-list-with-little-balls-gray-rectangle?

Comment: @Sebastiano I don't know anything about fonts:) Assuming that you have loaded the fonts you should be able to use them? Can you say more clearly in the question what you actually want? That is, explicitly say what fonts, and their sizes, you want to use, and where, in this environment. It would help if you could *also* cut your question down to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), so that it was clear what is actually needed to anwer your question.

Comment: Andrew I put above my MME, now.

Comment: @Sebastiano Hi! I was suggesting that you *edit* your follow-up question to make it clearer what you want. Please don't post code as an answer when it is meant to give more information to your question and *please* reduce the code (in your other question) so that it is as small as possible to demonstrate what your problem is. Posting a large chunk of code does not help people understand what you need. If in doubt consult  the definition of a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Hi, Andrew, you are definitely right; unfortunately I am learning very slowly and I make many mistakes. I ask you, if possible, in person if you can, to review and improve my code, make the appropriate changes etc. Thanks to your suggestion I'll try to narrow down the code and create a bulleted or numbered list to let you know how I would improve it. Basically I wish it was like a school text book, with a colorful header and different. Thanks veryyy muchhh.

Comment: With all my heart I thank you all sincerely. You are very talented and highly trained.