# Looking for a Times Roman math font that closely matches selected glyphs

Tags: fonts, times

I'd like to create some notes of Physics for a little thesis using Times Roman. I have seen one book of Physics with the following characters:

[image]

Is there a `Times Roman`-style LaTeX math font package that matches the glyphs highlighted by the red rectangles?

Comment: Imho your question is much to broad. You are asking to setup a full book layout which is the work of some hours -- this is not a suitable question for this site. Build the core layout yourself and then ask single questions for the parts where you don't find a solution yourself.

Comment: For the times font, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-do-i-make-my-document-use-the-times-font-both-for-the-text-and-the-math

Comment: Reminds me of [this earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346286/how-to-built-with-latex-a-nice-collection-of-exercises).  I thought i ad seen basicly the exact same question before, but i cannot find it.

Comment: @Sebastiano easiest would be having a look how others do it; e.g. https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/report displays reports. Then when you had a look in some, you can ask how to achive other things in it if you had a closer look yourself before.

Comment: For the `RMTMI` font: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mt11p?lang=en

Comment: There are multiple ways (packages) to get the fonts, there are multiple ways (packages) to get the bxes and there are multiple ways (packages) to get the marginal notes. That is breaking the system and what makes the question too broad.

Comment: If you ask for just the boxes, people will show you two, three or four ways to do it. Popular vote decides which way (package/answer) is the best. Same will work for the other aspects.

Comment: Those are fonts (or font-abbreviations, or identifiers), not packages.

Comment: You are asking for the combination of *all* fonts in the example, that alone is too-broad in my opinion. But you are also asking about the colorboxes. Which makes it even less to the point. Some users here on TeX.SX have asked hundreds of small questions. Most of them answerable with an effort of a few minutes.

Comment: What is `Greek-Roman`? The first 3 fonts are default. The last 4 you just load a Times clone package for. Look up the `RM...` one in `fontname` if this is a Berry font name. Which `Symbol` font? That one you probably just load the relevant symbol packages for. But combining CM maths and Times text is horrible. Don't do it.

Comment: But you are asking to combine CM maths and Times text. Why do you now say you don't want to?

Comment: @cfr You have right. Sorry. I've only seen the properties of the used fonts. @David Carlisle I wrote to me that the combination of the Times font with CM is horrendous. For this reason I wrote to you that I did not want that kind of font association. Even my request is closed. All I want is to figure out how to write a text that then I'll modify where you can use all these fonts. If the CM fonts can be deleted I take off. The text is written in Times-Roman, after a little research in CTAN, you can be activated with the `newtx` package, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx.

Comment: There is also this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-do-i-make-my-document-use-the-times-font-both-for-the-text-and- the-math, where I have read that I can use `\ usepackage {newtxtext, newtxmath}` or `\ usepackage {mathptmx}` . All I want is that I am told which packages use to have the fonts shown in the pictures.

Comment: For importing letters from another font, you can find the solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Comment: The main problem is that the Belleek fonts are in TeX Live, but there's no TFM file; building them would be very time consuming.

Comment: The history of that question could be turned into a detective story. It is very confusing. Requests change from day to day.

Comment: Maybe there was a glith in the matrix when the document you are referring to was created. You are just trying to recreate that glitch. Is it really worth the trouble?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title and body of your posting to state more succinctly what your objective is. If you feel I've misunderstood or misrepresented your actual objective, feel free to revert the posting to the earlier version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I take it that you're looking for a Times-Roman math font that closely (ideally: perfectly...) matches the shapes of four specific glyphs you've found in some document. These glyphs would be entered in a LaTeX document as `\gamma`, `\beta`, `v`, and `\Delta`, respectively.

For use with pdfLaTeX, I'm familiar with four font packages that provide a Times Roman-style *math* font: `mtpro2`, `newtxmath` (use the package option `varvw` to get the letters `v` and `w` with "rounded bottoms"), `mathptmx`, and `txfonts`. The complete `mtpro2` package is not free of charge; however, its "lite" subset -- which is all that's needed to produce these four glyphs -- *is* free. `mathptmx` and `txfonts` actually provide both a text font and a math font.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The glyphs differ not only in their shapes -- most obviously in the shape of the character `v` -- but also in their side-bearings. E.g., while the glyphs `\gamma`, `\beta`, and `\Delta` provided by the `newtxmath` package are pretty much identical to those provided by `txfonts`, their side-bearings differ considerably.

Based on these screenshots, I'd say you should be using the `mtpro2` package. The `newtxmath` package (if the option `varvw` is set) is probably OK as well.

If the online typesetting service (ShareLaTeX? Overleaf?) you're using doesn't provide access to the `mtpro2` package, I'd say that you may want to look into (a) setting up a full TeX distribution on your own computer and (b) downloading and installing either the lite or the full version of `mtpro2`.

Here's the code that produced the four screenshots; un-comment one of the packages at a time in order to recreate the screenshots shown above.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}

%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\ttfamily}p{2.75cm} p{1.15cm} p{0.9cm} @{}}
txfonts % select from: mtpro2[lite], newtxmath[varwv], mathptmx, txfonts
& $\gamma$ $\beta $ $v$ $\Delta$ & $\gamma\beta v\Delta$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, to address the OP's follow-up query: Here's an excerpt from page 7 of the user guide of MathTime Professional II font package, regarding the package's calligraphic math alphabets:

[image]

Comment: +1 There is also the `varg` and `varvw` options to `newtxmath`...

Comment: @AndrewSwann - Excellent point! Indeed, if `newtxmath` is loaded with the option `varvw`, the bottom of the `v` glyph is round rather than pointed. (The "entrance point" of the variant-v glyph is still pointed, though, unlike what's produced by the `mtpro2` package.)

Comment: @Mico Thanks a lot lot lot. Thanks for your very precious response. I have voted my question almost always negative. I tried with Overleaf and `mtpro2` works well. I must still download MiKTeX, install the editor, Ghostscript, etc..ma in this period I am very busy at school with my students. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - I've updated the MWE to show the output of `newtxmath` with the `varvw` option enabled. IMNSHO, the variant `v` and `w` glyphs of `newtxmath` are undistinguished hybrids of two distinct styles: (a) the "mtpro2 style", in which the glyphs have rounded entries and curves at the baseline, and (b)  the `txfonts`/`mathptmx` style, in which the glyphs have sharp corners both at the entry points and where they touch the baseline. In my view, the glyphs should use either rounded curves or sharp corners in both areas; mixing the styles looks too much like, well, a mixture...

Comment: Dear Mico, to website [mtp2lite](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite) there are too true type fonts for W7, for example. I have installed them do not work with Office Word. Why? Where do you find these fonts functional in `.ttf`? Could you add to your code courtesy of some calligraphic letters different? I only have the option `\mathcal{A}` but not other different calligraphic letters. I tried `\usepackage {array, times}
\usepackage [lite, mtpscr, mtpccal] {mtpro2}`but  I have trouble compiling. I am also interested to `mtc` (Mathtime Pro 2 Curly script).

Comment: @Sebastiano - I'm afraid I'm not an MS Word specialist, so I can't give you any (useful) hints on how to make some non-Word product work with Word. To be honest, it had never even occurred to me that the MathTime Pro II fonts might work with anything but TeX and LaTeX. The user guide of the mtpro2 package lists all math font shapes; did you check there?

Comment: @Mico I ask an extreme kindness: I have needed only two different calligraphic font `mtc` (Mathtime Pro 2 Curly script) or similar font that work with classical `\mathcal{A}` of computer modern + another calligraphic font. In fact I should write a tensor with a letter calligraphic different from the four-acceleration in my notes. At the site [mtp2lite](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/guide2.pdf) until on page 20 there is no trace of calligraphic fonts. `[lite, mtpscr, mtpccal] {mtpro2}` I can use them together with other calligraphic letters?

Comment: @Sebastiano - I've posted an addendum to my answer, to address your query about calligraphic font shapes that are provided by the `mtpro2` package. It turns out that in order to access the "script" and "curly" math alphabets, it is necessary to have full, i.e., non-free version of package; the "lite" subset won't do, I'm afraid.

Comment: But with \usepackage[lite] {mtpro2} exist another similar calligraphic font that I can use also with `times`?

Comment: @Sebastiano - The `lite` subset of the `mtpro2` package does not provide script, calligraphic, fraktur, and "holey" (aka blackboard bold) font shapes. Note also that the `mtpro2` package does not provide the CM-calligraphic or "Euler" math fonts either.

Comment: @Mico I have try that `\usepackage{array, times}, \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` the code `\[\mathcal{A} =(ict,\gamma X)\]` work correctly.

Comment: @Sebastiano - It works because the fontshape for `\mathcal` comes from Computer Modern (CM). That's precisely what I wrote in my previous comment, no? You may easily verify that the output of `$\mathcal{A}$` is the same whether or not the "lite" subset of `mtpro2` is loaded.

Answer (score 7):

The fonts you show are just Times Roman, plus the commercial MathTime font, a subset of mathtime is [available](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite) but not in texlive as it doesn't have a free licence. So here I use another math font based on math italic from the `newtxmath` package. Similarly I'm using the `newtxtext` Times Roman clone.

As you (still) hadn't provided an example, I made up some text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

something \textbf{bold} and \textbf{\textit{bold italic}}

$v/c$

and
\[
\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}
\]
and
$\pi^0\rightarrow\gamma+\gamma$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear David all perfect but the **v** (italic and bold) and `\pi` are different. These should match the fonts RMTMI font: ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mt11p?lang=en. But `\usepackage {mathptmx} ` can be used for **v** and `\pi`?

Comment: @Sebastiano use mathptmx instead of newtxmath if you prefer, there are by now lots of times clones available, just pick one you like, generally newtxmath is a more coherent set that mathptm which was mainly aimed at the capabilities of 1990's laser writers and the times roman and symbol fonts built in to those devices, if you prefer that font use it. but mathptmx has no bold math, as I recall.

Comment: Dearest David, but for v (italic and bold) and `\pi` (same style of the pictures) there are the fonts?

Comment: @Sebastiano i have no idea what font that is, you could try other fonts as well as I could:-) What is wrong with the newtxmath fonts, I'd just use that package and call it done.

Comment: Dear David I just changed the final request. Can you please help me how do you just change the two characters (`\pi` and `v`) of your answer?

Comment: Dearest David excuse me very much. I still have not put a MWE why should I reinstall MikTeX and so far I'm using Papeeria or Overleaf. really sorry.

Comment: @Sebastiano I don't see how whether you use miktex or overleaf has any connection with making an example to put in a question. Sorry I consider this question closed, if you need to ask more, better open a new question.

Answer (score 4):

If you can compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex` you could also try the TeX Gyre Termes fonts, which are based on Time New Roman, and provide support for Unicode Math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}

I'd like to create some notes of Physics for a little thesis using Times Roman. I
have seen one book of Physics with the following characters:
\[
    γ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-β^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}
\]
And this: $π^0\to γ+γ$ as well as:
\[
    Δt = γΔt_0\quad\text{time dilation}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure I really like the Greek characters very much, but others might.

You also (of course) need to be using an editor that supports Unicode text.  I use MacVim, and I have a custom keyboard layout that I use for maths, which has all the characters I regularly use.