# Exist a calligraphic fonts (free) similar at Mathtime Pro 2 Curly script?

Tags: fonts, mtpro, times, calligraphy

I ask if at the code of Mico's answer to my earlier question, [Looking for a Times Roman math font that closely matches selected glyphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355320/looking-for-a-times-roman-math-font-that-closely-matches-selected-glyphs),

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,times}

%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\ttfamily}p{2.75cm} p{1.15cm} p{0.9cm} @{}}
txfonts % select from: mtpro2[lite], newtxmath[varwv], mathptmx, txfonts
& $\gamma$ $\beta $ $v$ $\Delta$ & $\gamma\beta v\Delta$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

is possible (or exists) to add a similar calligraphic character that replaces **Mathtime Pro 2 Curly script** `mtc` [image] because I have only the `lite` subset of the `mtpro2` package and I haven't the full version of the `mtpro2 package`. I would need two calligraphic font, one of the classic modern computers and the other must be similar to writing children.

Comment: The `mtc` font requires the full version of `mtpro2`; the `lite` version doesn't provide it.

Comment: Which error?`times` is deprecated.

Comment: @egreg I have undestand after that `mtc` is it acronym for Mathtime Complete. Excuse me. But with `\usepackage[lite] {mtpro2}` I can have another similar calligraphic font that I can use also with `times`? Then I'll find on the internet somewhat similar font and gonna change it with Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: The option `lite` is incompatible with the options `mtpscr` and `mtpccal`. The latter two options only have an effect if you have the full version of the `mtpro2` package -- in which case you shouldn't set the `lite` option.

Comment: A separate concern: `mtc` does *not* stand for "MathTime Complete". It stands for "MathTime Curly script". Who told you otherwise?

Comment: With the greatest sincerity no one told me no. I just thought. But as my recent questions me negative vote them?

Comment: @Sebastiano I replaced the link you removed as the reference to `Mico's answer` makes no sense otherwise. But I am not sure why you keep editing this question in very minor ways. Insofar as I understand the question, it seems to have been answered by David and Mico. Insofar as I don't understand it, I think it really isn't clear what you want. As has been explained, you cannot use those options together. And you cannot use `mtpscr` and `mtpccal` unless you have purchased the fonts. The reference to Illustrator is also really unclear - what does that have to do with TeX?

Comment: @cfr I think that my question is clear; if you want you can change it to give a better sense. Since the fonts Mathtime Pro 2, and in particular, Curly scripts are chargeable and TeX uses these fonts only the lite version, I asked if there was a free font in TeX calligraphic it was similar to the shape of the A `mtc` Mathtime Pro 2 Curly script. The reference to Adobe Illustrator is simple: if there is no similar calligraphic font, I will try if there is A similar to the one written by kids. I hope that it was not you who put a negative vote :-).

Comment: Let me begin by stating that I am *not* the person who downvoted this posting. I must confess, though, to being perplexed as to what your objective is. It certainly doesn't help that you mention `mtc` and `cm` without providing at least some background as to where this material (and the associated screenshot) comes from. I assume this material is from the user guide of the `mathalfa` package, but I could well be wrong. The allusions to the `lite` subset of the `mtpro2` package don't help either. Please clarify whether or not you have access to the full version of the `mtpro2` package.

Comment: @Mico Exactly as you wrote it comes from the site: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf. I have the lite subset of the mtpro2 package and I haven't the full version of the `mtpro2` package. I do not even know what is it for to buy and how to install these fonts on MikTeX. Should I create a relativistic electrodynamics notes with characters that I have indicated. You are allowed to change if my question is not clear.

Comment: It was *not* me who down-voted your question. The problem with telling us to change your question to make it clearer is that we'd have to be clear what you wanted to ask, but that is obviously problematic when we are not sure what your purpose is. Do remember that the people who comment are not always the people who vote on posts, either up or down. If you assume that constructive criticism identifies down-votes to which you object, you will just dissuade people who might have helped you from commenting.

Comment: I hope my question is now clearer.

Comment: So why doesn't David's answer answer your question? [Calligraphic & handwritten fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html). [Fonts for maths](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html). Of course, you can use other fonts if something else is a better fit, though `fontspec` is needed for that to be a straightforward option.

Comment: @cfr I thank you very much for the links. David's answer is impeccable. I wanted to understand if there was simply a calligraphic font external or internal to the LaTeX. For example, if you saw this font [indis1](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxtYWVzdHJhbWFyaWthcm9uZ298Z3g6MWQ1NzE1MGEwYzdkZTBhOQ), I do the task at hand. You could load with LaTeX?

Comment: Yes. It is truetype. You can use it with `fontspec` in the usual way with XeTeX or LuaTeX. How well it would work in maths is another question, because the spacing might be wrong etc. But certainly you could use it. (Unless there is something odd about it - that's just a document illustrating the glyphs - not the font). You could even use it with pdfTeX if you really wanted to and learnt how to do it, but that is not a simple thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why those *particular* shapes?

As egreg mentioned in comments that's a commercial font, which is fine if that's what you want, there are no technical issues you just have to buy the font.

But there are plenty of script fonts around, You can easily have visually distinguished script fonts using fonts that are freely available and installed in TeXlive.

For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}


\DeclareMathAlphabet\urwscr{U}{urwchancal}{m}{n}%
\DeclareMathAlphabet\rsfscr{U}{rsfso}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\euscr{U}{eus}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\stixcal{LS2}{stixcal}{m} {n}
\begin{document}

$\mathcal{ABCDEF}$

$\rsfscr{ABCDEF}$

$\euscr{ABCDEF}$

$\urwscr{ABCDEF}$

$\stixcal{ABCDEF}$

\end{document}
```