# Script with curly S for successor function?

Tags: typography, logic

Very simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to; I'm writing a paper and I would like to use a script with a 'curly-tailed' capital S as is classically seen with the successor function in set theory, and I can't find one -- are there any?

Any text package recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here's a sketch of what I'm looking for.  I use capital letters for classes and fancier symbols for unary operations in general, which is why I'm looking for this particular script.

[image: .]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't know exactly what you mean with curly-tailed, but something like `$\mathcal{S}$`?

Comment: The greeting is appreciated!  I'm currently using the mathcal capital S, but it isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: `$\mathscr{E}$` has the 'curly tailed' property I'd like on S.

Comment: You could see at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358318/exist-a-calligraphic-fonts-free-similar-at-mathtime-pro-2-curly-script where there is a question on calligraphy fonts.

Comment: Those calligraphy fonts are much closer, thank you -- I'd ideally still like something that's just a 'no nonsense', constant width S with the above curling pattern on the tail.
I've already been through several pages on detexify after drawing what I was looking for to no avail.

Comment: The calligraphics from `euscript` are probably closest to this.

Comment: Then I'll use them, much appreciated!