# How to use multiple font packages at the same time?

Tags: fonts

I'm [referencing this pdf](http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~vollmer/pdfs/typesetting-script.pdf), but I want to use both Euler Script Font and Ralph Smith's Formal Script Font in different places in my document:

[image: here]

The problem is that they both seem to 'override' the `\mathscr` command; in that if I load `euscript` and then `mathrsfs`; and then use the `\mathscr` command, it will just come out as `mathrsfs`. How do I go about using both fonts in my document?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358336/1090

Answer (score 11):

Just don't use the `mathscr` option for the `euscript` package, so instead of `\mathscr` it'd provide `\EuScript` for these letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{euscript}
\begin{document}
\[
\EuScript{A}, \EuScript{B}, \mathscr{A}, \mathscr{B}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: euscript & mathrsfs]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}     
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo,calscaled=.97,bb=boondox]{mathalfa}
% \mathcal{R}+\pazocal{R}, normal+bold
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\pazocal{bold}{OMS}{zplm}{bx}{n}
\begin{document}
\[\mathcal A, \pazocal{D}, \mathscr A, \mathsf H \]
\end{document}
```