# Different \mathcal{J}

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

For my book I would like a specific symbol for "`J`" with a glyphs on the head as shown in the following images:

1. **First image**:

[image: This is a screenshot of my notes]

2. **Second image**:

[image]

Exist, peraphs, a command or a fine macro to obtain a similar shape?

Now I'm using now the packages `times` from https://ctan.org/pkg/times and `mtpro2` **v. lite** https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite and the classical calligraphic fonts using the command `\mathcal{J}`.

I would like that the symbol has the same size as the `\mathcal{T}` with the options **normal**, **the slanted (inclined)** and the **bold** character.

I often use `\boldsymbol{...}` command and I compile my file `.tex` only with `pdfLaTeX`.

Thanks to everybody for your precious help.

Comment: This symbol rather resembles a T for me.

Comment: No. It isn't a T. It is a J to indicate a quadrivector of the current. It is drawn with paint and has the graces.

Comment: Any pointer to a book or paper that uses the symbol?

Comment: isn't it just a J in some font as chosen by the book you are reading? any reader is going to see it as J and copy it down that way so normally it is better to use the consistent font in your document and not worry too much about the exact shape of the letter in other fonts.

Comment: Please give a screenshot for your 'J' but not your handwriting for it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, with adobe illustrator a symbol I managed to create it in pdf using the reduction command. I would not do the same procedure for this symbol.

Comment: @Kuttens I can only draw it at least for now. I believe that this symbol does not exist.

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't exist? If you see some publication take a photograph and upload that, but as I say I think it is better to use a J, isn't it the same J as https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/254442/how-is-4-current-a-4-vector

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can take, evening, a screenshot of my notes and I change the images. The J (Mathematical Double-Struck) is used here: https://www.amazon.com/Classical-Electromagnetic-Radiation-Third-Physics/dp/0486490602/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=3FJXAZAT0ARBM63SVV10

Comment: a screenshot of your notes wouldn't help, I mean take a shot of this J from whatever publication is using it.

Comment: Does wikipedia has the "J" symbol at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector at Electromagnetism part? Maybe a point for further searches?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  With a lot of sincerity I've never seen it on any kind of publication, book, etc.

Comment: @albert I thank you for the comment, but it is not the J of the site. I'm sorry.

Comment: @egreg Hi, my prof. of the course of **classical electrodynamics** use this symbol. I wished to know kindly whether it exists or not. I think,also, that there is not any text or publication that I know.

Comment: then you are just asking about finding a font to match your professor's _handwriting_ !!! why would you want to do that?

Comment: You have only seen the symbol hand written by someone on paper or a blackboard? Never printed?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Honestly because I like the symbol handmade and because I need different J.

Comment: sorry but it makes no sense to do that you could include an image of a handwritten j but it makes the digital form far less useful. It is a J just choose a font _for the whole document_ do not chose the look of each letter separately.

Comment: @Johannes_B Hi, blackboard :-(. I thought there was a strategy to do it using a basic character by modifying the glyphs of some resembling character.

Comment: There are at least three different ways to write the number one. You are asking what the symbol for one is, which you have never seen in handwriting before. Some other would just know it to be a one, not looking for a symbol. As noted before, the symbol you are looking for is the Latin letter J.

Comment: this is just the same as previous questions where you have asked about changing the shape of individual letters eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355320/looking-for-a-times-roman-math-font-that-closely-matches-selected-glyphs#comment876957_356261  just don't do that!

Comment: This is reminiscent of [Script-r Symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164493/117534). If you are really adamant about this, just do what Prof. Griffiths does for his script-r's (draw it out in vector form and `\includegraphics`). But honestly, I'ld recommend just sticking to what's conventional (for indicating four-vectors)..

Comment: @Troy Thank for your suggestion on link Script-r Symbol. I'm also studying on the Griffiths book. I have followed the same instructions to draw the calligraphic A of `mtpro2` package. :-). What do I remove the question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want a J with a T head :

- By using `adjusbox` you can cut out the J bottom and the T head.
  For example:
  `\def\hJ{\clipbox{0 -0.05ex 0 0.1em}{$J$}}
  \def\hT{\raisebox{0.45em}{\clipbox{0 0.45em 0 0em}{$T$}}}`
- You combine them with the suitable `\mkern`. Using the `mathllap` command from `mathtools` package :
  `$\mathllap{\hT}\mkern-15mu\hJ$` gies the desired symbol (mathtalic)

To get the bold or upright version you will have to adjust the kerning because the width is different. And for  boldface you will not be able to use `\bm` but will return to the old `\boldmath` put in another box. A compromise would be to pass the kern amount as a parameter :

```
\newcommand\JJ[1][15]{\hT\mkern -#1mu\hJ}
\newcommand\JJbf{\mbox{\boldmath$\JJ[14.2]$}}

  $\JJ  : \square \mathbf{A} = \mu_0 \,\JJbf$
```

produces the picture below. 
[image]

The makeshift (not a real solution) suggested  here should work with any font instead of the  default `latin modern` I used in the first picture. If you want to use another (math)font you simply would have to find the correct kerning, which is font dependent.
For the other variants (bold, upright etc.), simply add `\mathrm` or `\mathbf` or whatever needed in the definitions of `\hT` and `\hJ` (inside the `\clipbox`)
To get the result in the four mathstyles you will have to use `\mathchoice`, explained in several post on this forum.
Here is a full MWE using times and mtpro2 lite, and the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite,mtphbi]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}        
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\def\hJ{\mathchoice%
{\clipbox{0 -0.05ex 0 0.1ex}{$J$}}%
{\clipbox{0 -0.05ex 0 0.1ex}{$J$}}%
{\clipbox{0 -0.05ex 0 0.1ex}{$\scriptstyle J$}}%
{\clipbox{0 -0.05ex 0 0.1ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle J$}}%
}
\def\hT{\mathchoice%
{\raisebox{0.45ex}{\clipbox{0 0.45ex 0 0}{$T$}}}
{\raisebox{0.45ex}{\clipbox{0 0.45ex 0 0}{$T$}}}
{\raisebox{0.45ex}{\clipbox{0 0.45ex 0 0}{$\scriptstyle T$}}}
{\raisebox{0.45ex}{\clipbox{0 0.45ex 0 0}{$\scriptscriptstyle T$}}}
}

\def\hJbf{\mathchoice%
{\clipbox{0 -0.05ex 0 0.1}{$\mathbf{J}$}}%
{\clipbox{0 -0.05ex 0 0.1}{$\mathbf{J}$}}%
{\clipbox{0 -0.05ex 0 0.1}{$\scriptstyle \mathbf{J}$}}%
{\clipbox{0 -0.05ex 0 0.1}{$\scriptscriptstyle \mathbf{J}$}}%
}
\def\hTbf{\mathchoice%
{\raisebox{0.45ex}{\clipbox{0 0.45ex 0 0}{$\mathbf{T}$}}}
{\raisebox{0.45ex}{\clipbox{0 0.45ex 0 0}{$\mathbf{T}$}}}
{\raisebox{0.45ex}{\clipbox{0 0.45ex 0 0}{$\scriptstyle \mathbf{T}$}}}
{\raisebox{0.45ex}{\clipbox{0 0.45ex 0 0}{$\scriptscriptstyle \mathbf{T}$}}}
}

\newcommand\JJ[1][15.2]{\hT\mkern -#1mu\hJ}
\newcommand\JJbf[1][11.5]{\hTbf\mkern -#1mu\hJbf}

\begin{document}
\huge
A big regular J : $J\quad \mathrm{J}\quad \mathbf{J}$\par
A big regular T : $T\quad \mathrm{T}\quad \mathbf{T}$

This is custom J : $\JJ  \quad  \square \mathbf{A} = \mu_0 \,\JJbf$

$\JJbf_{\JJ_{\JJ}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I greatly appreciated your answer and voted for it positively. I like it but I would like to have the character that approaches the font times, normal style, that it is more vertical, like bold. For the inclined is fine. For my opinion my question has been misunderstood and it has been voted not appropriately.

Comment: I updated my answer with complete example using times and mtpro2, with option `mtphbi`. Should work with any.

Comment: You are very good and excellent answer. My question is not very bad. I check for your +15. Wonderful.

Comment: @egreg Hi. I have tried your code of this morning. I agree with you is not very nice to see. The user response has been exceptional.

Comment: I am getting `! LaTeX Error: File `mtpro2.sty' not found.` error

Comment: @alper Did you install the package and fonts ? `https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite`

Answer (score 3):

With `mathalfa` you can select from a large number of fonts. See [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode).

A symbol similar to yours is here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=pxtx]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{J}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it's not appropriate, check the table in Christian's answer for the aforementioned question.

Comment: How about something using `\ooalign` by combining a `T` with a `J`?