# Perfecting the product integral (integral sign with loop at the top)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I want to use this symbol for the [product integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral):

[image: product integral]

Perhaps with a bigger loop, too. What's the best way of building this notation?

---

I got it to work for just the integral sign itself.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\def\Prodint
{\adjustbox{trim = 0pt 0pt 0pt 0.15\height, clip} {$\displaystyle\int$} 
{\hspace{-0.45em} \mathrel{\raisebox{0.9em}{$\rho$}}}}

$$|\psi(t)\rangle=\Prodint U_t(dt)|\psi(0)\rangle$$
```

[image: Time evolution of quantum state]

But its behaviour with (especially lower) limits is really bad.

```
$$|\psi(t)\rangle=\Prodint_0^T U_t(dt)|\psi(0)\rangle\ne\int_0^T U_t(dt)|\psi(0)\rangle$$
```

[image]

How can I get the lower limit to be placed like in the standard `\int` (see above for reference)?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768 for instructions to "build your own".

Comment: Excuse me but where have you finded this symbol? I have not seen this symbol into your link.

Comment: You should check out https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en, but I doubt you will find it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo There is not :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I have not. I just thought it would be a cool symbol to use.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir Yes I have understood. But is there a link where have you taken the image?

Comment: @Sebastiano I made it in Paint. By attaching \rho to the integral sign.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir Ah ok. Infact your symbol not exist. You can see this question and best answer of the user Jhor https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428066/different-mathcalj. You should cut two symbols and glue them into exact position.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks! I managed to make the sign itself -- do you know how I can correct the positions of the limits (see the updated question)?

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir I hope I helped you a little bit. You have to say thanks to the excellent user egreg not to me :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're happy with the symbol, set the lower limit together with the integral, then add the upper limit to the whole block.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Prodint}{e{^_}}{%
  \mathop{}\!%
  {%
   \adjustbox{trim = 0pt -0.5pt 0pt 0.15\height, clip}{$\displaystyle\int\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}$}%
   \hspace{-0.45em}%
   \raisebox{0.9em}{$\rho$}%
  }%
  \IfValueT{#1}{^#1}%
  \!\mathop{}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_0^T f(t)\,dt \ne
\Prodint_0^T f(t)\,dt
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Question: did the addition of the `-0.5pt` to the trim actually change anything? It didn't change anything for me. Also, how do the `e` notation work -- do the `^` and `_` just represent `#1` and `#2` but with fancier notation than using square brackets? Is there some documentation for this, where it can be used?

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir Without it the lower limit could be cut because characters may overshoot a bit. Try with 0pt and you'll see.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very very much to have help the user Abhimanyu Pallavi Sudhir. Always thank you and I write it with all my heart.