# Why does mtpro2 lite font only work in Overleaf in some cases?

Tags: overleaf, mtpro

I want to use the `mtpro2` package in Overleaf but it seems to work only in some cases.

If I go to "new project", "blank project" and use this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

it says the `mtpro2.sty` file was not found. However, if I use the template

https://es.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-mtpro2-lite-fonts/ycyvptpzmkjf

and simply copy and paste the above it works perfectly.

I see no reason why Overleaf will find the package in one case and not in the other. In particular, in both cases, I am using pdfLaTeX compiler. It's starting to get a little annoying not finding the reason why it doesn't work.

PS. The template project doesn't have any other file in it, just the single `tex` file.

Edit: Apparently for some people it was working, so I created a public project to show the error.
https://www.overleaf.com/3449315768tszmmrnmspcs

Comment: I can compile your code well. Only the font doesn't change.

Comment: Erh, if I use your example in overleaf, it compiles with no errors. What exactly are you expecting should happen?

Comment: If I go through new project and blank project it doesn't compile. https://www.overleaf.com/3449315768tszmmrnmspcs
Is is just me?. @daleif

Comment: On Papeeria or on Overleaf `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` this type of font are not installed.

Comment: @DavidJaramillo then ask the Overleaf support staff. My guess, these two projects does not use the same latex installation. First project is using `TeX Live 2016/Debian`, your latest link is using `TeX Live 2017`.

Comment: My guess is that in the 2016 version it is just falling back to the Nimbus times clone. Since then the package has been removed from TeXLive as part of a general policy to not provide support files for commercial fonts.

Comment: You can see also a my old question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355320/looking-for-a-times-roman-math-font-that-closely-matches-selected-glyphs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.)

Since the template project was created in Overleaf v1, the new project based on the template is automatically created using Overleaf v1's TeX Live 2016 image, which includes certain non-free fonts, including MTPro2 Lite. (Even though the font is "free as in free beer" it doesn't meet all the criteria of free/libre software in order to be included in TeX Live outright.)

When creating a new blank project, the newer Overleaf v2 (from the merger with ShareLaTeX) compiler image is used. (This is currently TeX Live 2017, but we will be releasing an updated image in the coming months.) This compiler image does not include the non-free fonts.

As a workaround, you might instead use `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}` from the `newtx` package, a more robust and updated free version of the TX fonts.

Comment: But `MTPro2 Lite` is free, right? Also, are you saying that `newtx` is more robust than `MTPro2`?

Comment: @zdm as mentioned in the answer, it's free as in free beer, but not free as in free/libre software that can be included in TeX Live. More information on this is here: https://tug.org/texlive/copying.html The EULA for MTPro2 is here: https://pctex.com/files/managed/9/96/EULA-MTPro2.txt (it doesn't specifically mention the Lite version here, but you have to agree to this to download the Lite version from the website). And yes, `newtx` is more robust than MTPro2 _Lite_ specifically. `newtxmath` contains many of the math alphabets that are not included in the Lite version of MTPro2.

Comment: I see. Thank you