# Package to select exercises by difficulty

Tags: packages, package-writing

I'm new to this community, I'm sorry if the question is not appropriated.

I'm looking for a package to create Exercise Sheets like [probsoln](https://ctan.org/pkg/probsoln), with exercises loaded from an outside .tex file, but that I can assign an integer (the difficulty) to each problem and choose the appropriate difficulty for the questions of my exercise sheet. Is there such a package? If not, is there a quick way to add this feature o probsln?

Ideally, I'd chose a distribution of difficulty for the test, e.g.: questions 1 to 5 chosen from those with difficulty < 200, from 6 to 10 with difficulty from 200 to 400 and so on.

Comment: You can see also this link. It is my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346286/how-to-built-with-latex-a-nice-collection-of-exercises

Comment: See the package: [eqexam](https://ctan.org/pkg/eqexam)

Comment: Does it have to be random?