# Adjusting the alignment of footnote numbers

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

In relation to a recent previous issue [A nice type of footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472018/a-nice-type-of-footnote), I have readjusted the values of the code provided by the very good user @Henri Menke because the gray line was too much on the left and was not aligned with the numbers of the footnotes. Now it's almost perfect, but I can't align the first nine notes all on the right. In fact, there is not a correct numerical alignment as you can see in the screenshot that I attach.
How I can solve this problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \noindent
  \kern0pt
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-10pt]
    \fill[darkgray,path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (.4\columnwidth,0.02);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \kern2.6pt
}

\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{9pt}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{9pt}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{5mm}
\begin{document}
First word\footnote{One}, Second word\footnote{Two},  Second word\footnote{Two},  Second word\footnote{Two},  Second word\footnote{Two},  Second word\footnote{Two},  Second word\footnote{Two}, Second word\footnote{Two},  Second word\footnote{Two}, Second word\footnote{Two}, Second word\footnote{Two}, Second word\footnote{Two}, Second word\footnote{Two}, Second word\footnote{Two}, Second word\footnote{Two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove `hang`: `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because @marmot has solved my problem with your comment.