# Defining a command which makes a new symbol

Tags: symbols

Is there a way to define a new command which represents the function override symbol used in Event-B. There is a similar symbol `\dsub` that is just the triangle with the line that splits it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What is Event-B?

Comment: @cfr Event-B is a language that uses mathematical structures to develop system models for areas such as Critical Systems

Comment: @cfr http://rodin.cs.ncl.ac.uk/deliverables/D7.pdf

Comment: My point is that your question shouldn't assume discipline-specific knowledge unless it really has to. If something is crucial, you need to explain it. The name of a symbol and context may be useful, but only as a supplement. I can't tell from your question whether the symbol you've shown is the one you need or `\dsub`, which seems to match the description.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At https://sourceforge.net/p/rodin-b-sharp/svn/16394/tree/trunk/Handbook/org.rodinp.handbook.feature/latex/plastex-bsymb.sty, they provide `bsymb.sty` and employ this definition

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\ovl}{\mathbin{\lhd\mkern-9mu-}} 
\begin{document}\Huge
$\ovl{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

According to this site, http://wiki.event-b.org/index.php/Rodin_Keyboard_User_Guide, there is a unicode symbol      U+E103 , but I haven't yet found a font that supports it (I see some web reference to one called Brave Sans Mono that might support it, but haven't found the actual font yet).

The Event-B language is discussed in great detail at http://rodin.cs.ncl.ac.uk/deliverables/D7.pdf

Comment: @Sebastiano A little bit of sleuthing on a Monday morning.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Do you remember this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337356/create-a-custom-numbered-list-with-little-balls-and-gray-rectangle-also-with-th. You were the first to help me with my first question.

Comment: @Sebastiano Oh yes, that was a good question and fun to work on.  This one was much more poking around on the web.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes But it had little reputation in terms of score.:-( why not do a bit of advertising? :-)