# A function or macro to create an RPG-style bullet points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, draw

I'm looking to create a function or a macro that takes as an input a number `n` between 0 and 5 and returns five circles with the `n` leftmost circles filled, something like this:

[image: circles, some filled]

I'm still reading documentation, but I've never made a macro or a function like this before, so I cannot show a MWE. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, basically the same macro you'll find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408529/tikz-foreach-experience-bar), but modified a bit to look like the picture you posted (No underline dots included).

To use it just put `\dotexp{<n>}` wherever you need.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{rpgblue}{HTML}{1A5A75}

\newcommand{\dotexp}[1]{%
\edef\DEnum{\the#1}%
\tikz{\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{\draw[rpgblue,fill=rpgblue] ({\x/2.5+0.01},0) circle (.58ex);
      \ifnum\x>\DEnum
        \def\DEfill{white}%
      \else
        \def\DEfill{rpgblue}%
      \fi
      \draw[\DEfill,fill=\DEfill] (\x/2.5,0) circle (.5ex);}}%
    }

\begin{document}
\newcount\x
\x=0
\loop
 \the\x\dotexp{\x}

 \advance \x by 1
 \ifnum\x<6
\repeat
\end{document}
```