# How to define a style of undefined key choice?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, pgfkeys

I would like to implement something like `default` in a `switch` statement, but for `.is choice` pgf key. I know that there is an error key handler `/errors/unknown choice value` but I don't know how to use it. Or may be there is a solution without implementing this handler ?

What I want is when I define for example `test/.is choice`, to be able to define something like `test/.else style={...}` that is executed for any `test=<unknown choice>` with `#1` set to `<unknown choice>` (like if `test` was not a choice).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  test/.is choice,
  test/1/.style={red},
  test/2/.style={blue},
  % test/.else style={yellow} <-- how to implement this ?
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[test=1] circle(3);
    \fill[test=2] circle(2);
    \fill[yellow] circle(1); % I would like [test=007]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:* I asked myself this question when I was writing [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426488/9335).

**EDIT** After [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426495/9335) of @TeXnician I want to specify that I would like to be able to declare something like `test/.else style={#1}` and then use it like this `test=yellow` (the parameter is important for me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not search for `.else`, but for `.unknown` (see section 82.3.6 in the TikZ manual).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  test/.is choice,
  test/1/.style={red},
  test/2/.style={blue},
  test/.unknown/.style={yellow}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[test=1] circle(3);
    \fill[test=2] circle(2);
    \fill[test=007] circle(1); % I would like [test=007]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

As for requirement two: using the key given you can use it as `\pgfkeyscurrentname`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  test/.is choice,
  test/1/.style={red},
  test/2/.style={blue},
  test/.unknown/.style={\pgfkeyscurrentname}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[test=1] circle(3);
    \fill[test=2] circle(2);
    \fill[test=yellow] circle(1); % I would like [test=007]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer that ask one part of my question, because the `#1` is not set to `007` like this. Sorry, my example was not clear :(

Comment: This is what I was searching for, thanks ! I tried `\pgfkeyscurrentvalue` but it was not defined ;)

Comment: The bad news for me is that `.list={1,...,\pgfkeyscurrentname}` is not working, where `.list={1,...,#1}` is working :(

Comment: @Kpym That's probably, because it does not expand properly. Maybe you should ask this as new question.

Comment: I know, I should ask another question, but probably not today ... thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I have my expansion  (not very nice) solution with `.unknown/.prefix code={\edef\pgfkeyscurrentchoice{\pgfkeyscurrentname}}` and then use `\pgfkeyscurrentchoice` in place of `\pgfkeyscurrentname` in `.list={1,...,\pgfkeyscurrentchoice}`.